# Maven test doesn't pass on Windows 10 because of encoding

Tags: java, maven, encoding, windows-10

I have project on Spring Boot, Java and Maven, but my test doesn't pass because actual result I get something like "РўРµРєСЃС‚" (I use non-latin letters). But when I launch tests in IntelliJ IDEA, they pass correctly. I have no plugin "maven-surefire-plugin" in pom.xml.
I tried

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

and

```
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
    </configuration>
```

What can I do to make tests pass?

Comment: Which version of surefire-plugin do you use? Also please show the tests... Which version of JDK, Spring Boot etc. do you use?

Comment: JDK 17, SB 2.7.0, in pom.xml there are no surefire plugin

Comment: Using Spring Boot means it's defining maven-surefire-plugin on it's own.. you should check the logging output which versions is being used?

Comment: maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1
maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0, it already has log "Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources."
maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2, no mention encoding in logs

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the encoding for the maven-surefire-plugin.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>YOUR_VERSION</version>
      <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: thanks, but adding it to project didn't help

Comment: This property is implicitly set by using `project.build.sourceEncoding` See https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#encoding